# Classic ASP debugging frame content in frameset with VS2010 IIS 7

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, asp-classic, frameset

Im trying to step through a classic asp page which is hosted in iis7 in Visual Studio 2010. Ive followed a few blogs, mainly these ones:
"http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/06/24/432308.aspx"
"http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/eff76bd0-6421-4ba5-b063-a348eec27ebb"

It seems that the breakpoint I set is not hit when I browse to the page in question, I think this is because the application is all in frames. When monitoring the process in sql profiler it looks like all session information is gathered once the page starts up, having been browsed to from iis7, after I log in using the login page it doesnt actually get any more information.

Has anybody got any tips for debugging frames in classic asp with VS2010 and iis7?

UPDATE: Turns out there was a hidden setting in the database that meant when I ran the application up it was going to a different system.... which would explain why it wasnt hitting the code - Visual Studio 2008 actually told me in advance that the breakpoint wouldnt be hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using the vbscript keyword "stop" in my source code. this is just like a breakpoint in visual studio. a window pops asking you which debugger you want to use, select visualsudio 2010 and you're fine...

you have to set server debugging to true in iis 7 (asp section)